# Azure API Management Services API Create

Tags: azure

I am new to AZure , I am just trying the few services of Azure. So, I have created one REst Service Application and now I want to add it in Azure APi Management Service. Its asking for Web Public API URL/Suffix . How I will get it ?

Comment: Any luck @Prince?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes first you have to deploy it on tomcat of Azure from there you will get the URL that needs to be added.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! Would you mind confirming my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure API Management, the suffix is your public facing URI. It appends to `https://myAPIexampleManagement.azure-api.net/`.

[image]

In this case for developers to access your service which is located at `http://my.backend.service.io` (Your REST application) they would have to address to `https://myAPIexampleManagement.azure-api.net/root`

In conclusion, your Web API URL suffix can be whatever you want it to be.